# Perl - If table does not exist

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm currently using the following which works but throws an error every time the table is created (as it is first trying to insert into a db which does not exist and returning false).

```
$result = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `". $host ."` (URL) VALUES ('$href')");
if( ! $result->execute() ){
    $result = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `" . $host . "` ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ENGINE = MYISAM ;");
    $result->execute();
    print "Host added: " . $host . "\n";
}
```

Could someone let me know of a more efficient way of completing this task?

EDIT - Bind

```
$result = $dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE `?` If NOT EXISTS ( `ID` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `URL` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY ( `ID` )) ENGINE = MYISAM ;");
            $result->execute($host);
            $result = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `?` (URL) VALUES ('?')");
            $result->execute($host, $href);
            print "Host added: " . $host . "\n";
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE TABLE Foo if NOT EXISTS  <schema>
```

Also, please use placeholders and bind values in your INSERT operations, lest you be known as [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: About this 'bind' thing, can you check the edit in the question to see if it correct?

Comment: Actually you can't use placeholders for table names (for most drivers), so the edited code will fail.

Comment: @CanSpice: it definitely varies. MySQL will allow prepared statements for identifiers in *some* circumstances, but usually only if you sacrifice a chicken and mutter the right incantation first - e.g. see the evil tricks in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html.

Comment: @Phil: an alternative to placeholders for your table names would be to use the `quote_identifier` function in DBI -- `$dbh->prepare("CREATE TABLE " . $dbh->quote_identifier($host) . " IF NOT EXISTS ...")`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE tblname IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a web app?  If so, I highly recommend against using a user/pass that has rights to alter the database structure.  A more typical method would be to have an installer script that creates the tables up front.

Comment: Why not implment it in a single table, with Host being a column name that you can filter on?

Comment: @Phil if you don't know what they're going to be called, your database design is broken :)

Answer (score 0):

If you expect the table to exist more often than not, the existing code *is* the most efficient way.  Note that you can override PrintError and RaiseError (assuming one of those is what you mean by "throws an error") for a given statement handle.